# Can I extend xamarin WatchOS to android as well?

Tags: xamarin, watchos-2

I have to create a small iWatch app. i am confused if I should go ahead with Xamarin WatchOS or swift. Can xamarin WatchOS be extended to android wear? what to go with?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No.  WatchOS is an Apple SDK.  Android uses the Wear SDK.  They are two completely different things.  You may be able to share some backend code between the two platforms using Xamarin.

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/Hanselman.Forms 
this is an excellent way of extending xamarin into WatchOS.